# Symfony retrieve the id of the filled-in entity in the previous form

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony

I will try to explain as best as possible. I created 2 linked entities for a @manytoone bidirectional relationship (I believe ^^ '). Here is what I want to do, I create a first form that allows me to fill the first entity (the daughter entity) and then I am redirected according to criteria to another page that allows me to fill the parent entity but I Can not find a way to retrieve the id of the entity girl, I tried to pass it through the URL but I can not retrieve it and insert it in the field id_daughterentities.
I enclose the code, I hope that this explanation will allow you to see more clearly.

```
public function newclientAction(Request $request)
{
    // On crée un objet Advert
    $client = new Clients();

    // J'ai raccourci cette partie, car c'est plus rapide à écrire !
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(FormType::class, $client)
        ->add('FirstName',      TextType::class)
        ->add('Surname',      TextType::class)
        ->add('Address',      TextType::class)
        ->add('Mail',      EmailType::class, array(
            'required' => false))
        ->add('Mail2',   EmailType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Mail N°2',
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('Phone',      TextType::class, array(
            'required' => false))
        ->add('Phone2',     TextType::class, array('label' => 'Phone N°2',
            'required' => false))
        ->add('BirthDate',    BirthdayType::class, array('label' => 'Date of Birth'))
        ->add('Status',     ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices'  => array(
                'Client' => 'Client',
                'Ex-Client' => 'Ex-Client',
                'Prospect' => 'Prospect'),
        ))
        ->add('Comments',     TextareaType::class, array(
            'required' => false))
        ->add('TypeofBuisness', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices'  => array(
                'Blank'=> Null,
                'SE' => 'SE',
                'SA' => 'SE',
                'LLP' => 'LTD',
                'LTD' => 'LTD',
                'Payroll' => 'Payroll'),
                'label' => 'Type of buisness'
        ))
        ->add('save',      SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm()
    ;

    // Si la requête est en POST
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        // On fait le lien Requête <-> Formulaire
        // À partir de maintenant, la variable $advert contient les valeurs entrées dans le formulaire par le visiteur
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // On vérifie que les valeurs entrées sont correctes
        // (Nous verrons la validation des objets en détail dans le prochain chapitre)
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // On enregistre notre objet $advert dans la base de données, par exemple
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($client);
            $em->flush();

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Well regitered.');
            if ($client->getTypeOfBuisness()== 'Payroll')
            {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('pegasus_payroll', array('id' => $client->getId()));
            }
            elseif ($client->getTypeOfBuisness()== 'LTD')
            {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('pegasus_ltd', array('id' => $client->getId()));
            }
            elseif ($client->getTypeOfBuisness()== 'LTD')
            {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('pegasus_se', array('id' => $client->getId()));
            }
            else {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('pegasus_web_homepage', array('id' => $client->getId()));
            }
        }
    }

    // À ce stade, le formulaire n'est pas valide car :
    // - Soit la requête est de type GET, donc le visiteur vient d'arriver sur la page et veut voir le formulaire
    // - Soit la requête est de type POST, mais le formulaire contient des valeurs invalides, donc on l'affiche de nouveau
    return $this->render('PegasusWebBundle:Default:newclient.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
public function payrollAction(Request $request)
{
    // On crée un objet Advert
    $payroll = new Payroll();

    // J'ai raccourci cette partie, car c'est plus rapide à écrire !
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(FormType::class, $payroll)
        ->add('EmployerName',      TextType::class, array('label' => 'Employer name'))
        ->add('EmployerSurname',      TextType::class)
        ->add('Address',      TextType::class, array('required' => false))
        ->add('Phone',      TextType::class, array('required' => false))
        ->add('Phone2',     TextType::class, array('label' => 'Phone N°2','required'=> false))
        ->add('Mail',      EmailType::class, array('required' => false))
        ->add('Mail2',   EmailType::class, array('label' => 'Mail N°2','required'=> false ))
        ->add('ContactName',      TextType::class, array('required' => false))
        ->add('Payedisctrict',      TextType::class, array('label' => 'PAYE district','required'=> false))
        ->add('Payeaddress',      TextType::class, array('label' => 'PAYE address','required'=> false))
        ->add('Payephone',      TextType::class, array('label' => 'PAYE phone','required'=> false))
        ->add('Payereference',      TextType::class, array('label' => 'PAYE reference','required'=> false))
        ->add('Accref',      TextType::class, array('label' => 'Account reference','required'=> false))
        ->add('Taxereff',      TextType::class, array('label' => 'Tax reference','required'=> false))
        ->add('Comments',     TextareaType::class, array('label' => 'Any comment ?','required'=> false))
        ->add('save',      SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm()
    ;
```

I tried there to take the id from the url but it's not working, i tried tones of solutions but nothing works .... I really sorry for this stupid question but i'm trying to learn it by my own

```
    $payroll.clients=$request->query->get('id');


    // Si la requête est en POST
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        // On fait le lien Requête <-> Formulaire
        // À partir de maintenant, la variable $advert contient les valeurs entrées dans le formulaire par le visiteur
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $payroll->is

        // On vérifie que les valeurs entrées sont correctes
        // (Nous verrons la validation des objets en détail dans le prochain chapitre)
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // On enregistre notre objet $advert dans la base de données, par exemple
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($payroll);
            $em->flush();

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Well regitered.');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('pegasus_web_homepage');

        }
    }

    // À ce stade, le formulaire n'est pas valide car :
    // - Soit la requête est de type GET, donc le visiteur vient d'arriver sur la page et veut voir le formulaire
    // - Soit la requête est de type POST, mais le formulaire contient des valeurs invalides, donc on l'affiche de nouveau
    return $this->render('PegasusWebBundle:Default:newclient.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

```
/**
 * Payroll
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="payroll")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pegasus\WebBundle\Repository\PayrollRepository")
 */
class Payroll
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Clients", inversedBy="payroll")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="clients_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $clients;

     /**
     * Set clients
     *
     * @param \Pegasus\WebBundle\Entity\Clients $clients
     *
     * @return Payroll
     */
    public function setClients(\Pegasus\WebBundle\Entity\Clients $clients )
    {
        $this->clients = $clients;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get clients
     *
     * @return \Pegasus\WebBundle\Entity\Clients
     */
    public function getClients()
    {
        return $this->clients;
    }
```

Cause of that i can't validate my form because my foreign key is empty ... :/
Someone can help me ? pls

Comment: Have you tried searching for solution? This is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423286/symfony-pasing-values-from-one-form-to-another

Comment: Yes i try, but didn't find something for me. I didn't understand this solution or the solution is not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need the `Clients` Entity object to persist the doctrine entity, not the integer ID. If you are passing the id in your request, you'll need to either use automatic Dependency Injection, or get the entity from doctrine manually, like so:

```
$clients = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->find('PegasusWebBundle:Clients', $request->query->get('id'));
```

The next issue is your Payroll form. It needs to be made aware of the `Payroll` entity (`data_class` option) and the `Clients` `EntityType` association, even if clients is a hidden field. Though it is unclear in your example how you are passing the form data to the `new Payroll` entity object.

For example using separate GET and POST actions.

```
/**
 * @Route("/pegasus_payroll/{id}", name="pegasus_payroll", requirements={"id":"\d+"})
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function payrollAction(Request $request, \Pegasus\WebBundle\Entity\Clients $clients)
{
     $payroll = new Payroll();
     //set the new payroll clients based on the automatic param conversion
     $payroll->setClients($clients);
     $form = $this->createPayrollForm($payroll, ['action' => $this->generateUrl('save_pegasus_payroll')]);
     $form->handleRequest($request);

     return $this->render('PegasusWebBundle:Default:newpayroll.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
     ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/pegasus_payroll", name="save_pegasus_payroll")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function savePayrollAction(Request $request)
{
     //retrieve the entity from the request form data, to validate with the previous form choice(s).
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $clients = $em->find('PegasusWebBundle:Clients', $request->request->get('form')['clients']);
     $payroll = new Payroll;
     $payroll->setClients($clients);
     $form = $this->createPayrollForm($payroll);
     $form->handleRequest($request);
     if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
         $formPayroll = $form->getData();
         echo $formPayroll->getClients()->getId();
         //the form data is propagated to the $payroll object passed to it
         echo $payroll->getClients()->getId();
         exit;
         //$em->persist($payroll);
         //$em->flush();
         //$this->addFlash('notice', 'Well regitered.');

         //return $this->redirectToRoute('pegasus_web_homepage');
     }

     return $this->render('PegasusWebBundle:Default:newpayroll.html.twig', [
         'form' => $form->createView(),
     ]);
}

/**
 * use a method to store the form so you can use it elsewhere
 * Alternatively create a new FormType class that extends AbstractFormType
 */
private function createPayrollForm(Payroll $payroll, array $options = []) 
{
     $options['data_class'] = Payroll::class;

     return $this->get('form.factory')
         ->createBuilder(FormType::class, $payroll, $options)
         //.. you will need to update to match the Payroll entity property name getter/setters names.
         ->add('clients', EntityType::class, [
             'class' => \Pegasus\WebBundle\Entity\Clients::class,
             'multiple' => false, //only a single selection
             'label' => false, //don't display the form field label
             'choice_label' => false, //don't display select options
             'choices' => [$payroll->getClients()], //only available choice
             'attr' => [
                 'style' => 'display:none;' //hide the select box
             ]
        ])
        ->getForm();
}
```

---

As a final note, you should take advantage of the automatic Dependency Injection using [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)
It will make your life a lot easier when your controllers have type-hinted what they are requiring, rather than having to manually define evertything.

Comment: I didn't understand the second part of your answer so I try : `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find('PegasusWebBundle:Clients',$request->query->get('id'));
                     $payroll->setclients();`    But my id_clients is still empty in my DB don't know why

Comment: In all of the actions, you need to ensure `$payroll->setClients($clients)` is not empty. So using your snippet: `$clients = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find('PegasusWebBundle:C‌​lients',$request->qu‌​ery->get('id'));` then you need to set the clients of payroll using `$payroll->setClients($clients);` Then when you call `persist` and `flush` on payroll, payroll will have the clients assigned to it.

Comment: If you're not using the automatic ParamConverter, you will need to check the retrieval of the entity and display an appropriate error. `if (!$em->find('Entity', $id)) { //error }` Otherwise `find` can return `null`

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer as accepted so that others know that your question has been answered.